# Linear span of $SO(n)$

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

Problem:

> Describe the linear span of $SO(n, \mathbb{R})$ over $\mathbb{R}$ with a system of equations

I managed to solve it for $n=2$, where the matrices $A = [a_{ij}]$ have to satisfy $a_{11} = a_{22}, a_{12} =- a_{21}$.

For $n=3$ I presume $a_{ij} = -a_{ji}$ for $i \neq j$, but can't show that any matrix in $SO(3)$ these equality holds.

Can you help me please?

Comment: Surely you mean $a_{12} = -a_{21}$. Also, in $SO(3)$ one has the cyclic permutations of the standard basis vectors, whose matrices do not satisfy the anti-symmetry you described.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *linear span* of $SO(n,\mathbb R)$? When $n\ne 2$, that is simply all of $\mathbb R^{n\times n}$:

For $n=3$ we have, for example,
$$ \begin{bmatrix}0&0&0\\1&0&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix} = \frac12 \begin{bmatrix}&-1\\1\\&&1\end{bmatrix} + \frac12 \begin{bmatrix}&1\\1\\&&-1\end{bmatrix} $$
and there are similar constructions for all of the other diagonal and off-diagonal entries.

For $n=4$ you can use the same construction, except that it may not cancel out all unwanted diagonal elements. But this can be corrected for, using multiples and permutations of
$$ \begin{bmatrix}4\\&0\\&&0\\&&&0\end{bmatrix} = I +
\begin{bmatrix}1\\&1\\&&-1\\&&&-1\end{bmatrix} +
\begin{bmatrix}1\\&-1\\&&1\\&&&-1\end{bmatrix} +
\begin{bmatrix}1\\&-1\\&&-1\\&&&1\end{bmatrix}
$$

And this generalizes nicely to $n>4$. (As well as to any base field of characteristic $\ne 2$).

Answer (score 0):

I dont think the last thing you wrote is correct. Maybe try the following "a matrix in $SO(n)$ has the property that, if you multiply it by its transpose you get the identity". The transpose sends $a_{ij}$ to $a_{ji}$. you should also be able to say what matrix multiplication is in terms of the $a_{ij}$. Multiplying the matrix and its transpose together and setting equal to the identity, you should get the equations you want